# Constraining Data Types

Tags: haskell, types, representation

Suppose you have a nice inductive definition and you want to define it as a data type in Haskell. However, your inductive definition is (as many inductive definitions are) of such a form that the generating rules require their 'premisses' to have a certain structure. For instance, suppose we have the following definition:

- if `x` is an even integer, then `T x` is a weapon,
- if `x` is an odd integer, then `S x` is a weapon.

If I want to define this (as a single) data type in Haskell, I would write something like

```
data Weapon =  T Int | S Int
```

Obviously, this will not work as you now can generate `T 5` and `S 4`, for instance. Is there a natural way to pass on restrictions on the constructor arguments, so that I could write something similar to the above code which would give the correct definition?

Comment: Smart constructors, mostly. Forbid using `T` and `S` directly, and create `newT` and `newS` functions that verify the numbers passed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best shot is not to export `T` and `S` explicitly, but allow a custom constructor:

```
module YourModule (Weapon, smartConstruct) where

data Weapon =  T Int | S Int

smartConstruct :: Int -> Weapon
smartConstruct x
    | even x     = T x
    | otherwise  = S x
```

Now when importing `YourModule`, users won't be able to create `T` and `S` explicitly, but only with your `smartConstruct` function.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit un-Haskelly, but is more idiomatic in e.g. Agda: change the interpretation of your representation so that it is forced to be correct by construction.

In this case, notice that if `n :: Int`, then `even (2 * n)` and `odd (2 * n + 1)`. If we handwave away the case of too large `Int`s, we can say there's a bijection between the even `Int`s and the `Int`s; and another one between the odd `Int`s and the `Int`s.

So using this, you can choose this representation:

```
data Weapon = T Int | S Int
```

and change its interpretation such that the value `T n` actually represents `T (2 * n)` and the value `S n` represents `S (2 * n + 1)`. So no matter what `n :: Int` you choose, `T n` will be valid since you will regard it as the "`T`-of-2*n" value.

Comment: Nice. Do you happen to know where could I find more examples of this kind of trick?

Comment: And you can remove the handwave with `Integer`.

Comment: @danidiaz: there are several instances of this pattern in the Agda standard library, e.g. check out http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/html/Data.Integer.html#915

Comment: The link above is 404 now; the new correct one is http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Agda.Builtin.Int.html#178

Answer (score 5):

*If* you are willing to restrict yourself to using Nats, and are ok with using reasonably advanced type magic, you can use `GHC.TypeLits`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, TypeOperators, KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data Weapon (n :: Nat) where
    Banana      :: n ~ (2 * m) => Weapon n
    PointyStick :: n ~ (2 * m + 1) => Weapon n

banana :: Weapon 2
banana = Banana

pointyStick :: Weapon 3
pointyStick = PointyStick
```

try for yourself, that it won't compile with wrong (odd/even) numbers.

**Edit:** More practical is probably cactus' approach though.

Comment: This seems sort of dual to the request. Interesting, though.

Comment: I also appreciate the Monty Python reference.

Comment: why do you think it is dual? you need to go to some lengths to construct these natty weapons on runtime, but it's not hard (and a different kind of question). it does guarantee that only even bananas and odd pointy sticks gets constructed though.